# Packet Processing in NetFilter Hooks ?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Looking for Information on NF_STOLEN.

After Stealing Packet from NET-FILTER ; am adding IP Header by expanding SKUBUFFER. After that; want to send the Packet to the corresponding Interface . What is the function that we should use to do this step ??? OR if we say; NF_ACCEPT., can we ensure that Manipulated Packet will be processed by the Kernel correctly forwarding it to the right interface ??

Looking forward for the reply !!!

-Thanks in Advance,
VKS

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you alter the skbuff structure and compute the appropriate checksums, you just need to return NF_ACCEPT. The kernel will deal with the rest for you.

I've done this in my thesis. Here's some code I've done (it does not extend or trim the skbuff, but it changes a field in the application payload. However, I've also done some code which extends the skbuff and the theory is the same):

```c
unsigned int pre_routing_hook(filter_specs* sp, unsigned int hooknum,
                              struct sk_buff* skb, const struct net_device* in,
                              const struct net_device *out, 
                              int(*okfn)(struct sk_buff*)) {
    struct iphdr* iph;
    struct udphdr* udp;
    __tp(pdu)* pdu;

    /*Omitted some sanity checks */

    iph = ip_hdr(skb);
    udp = (struct udphdr*) (((char*) iph) + (iph->ihl << 2));

    //I didn't care about udp checksum so I've stored zero in this field.
    udp->check = 0;

    switch (iph->protocol) {
    case IPPROTO_UDP:
          pdu = (__tp(pdu)*) (((char*) iph) + (iph->ihl << 2)
                               + sizeof(struct udphdr));

          swap_pdu_byte_order(pdu);

          pdu->timestamp = get_kernel_current_time() - 
                           (pdu->timestamp + pdu->rtt * 1000); 

          swap_pdu_byte_order(pdu);
          break;
    default:
            printk("\tProtocol not supported.\n");
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

**EDIT**: I've took a look at the code you've posted and here's what I came up with. It works for me:

```c
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>


static uint16_t csum(uint16_t* buff, int nwords) {
    uint32_t sum;
    for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
            sum += *buff++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);

    return ((uint16_t) ~sum);
}

//I'm assuming this will run in PRE_ROUTING                                                                                                  
unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum,
            struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in,
                   const struct net_device *out, int(*okfn)(struct sk_buff*)) {
  uint16_t lets_keep_the_original_size;
  struct in_device* ipa;

  iph = ip_hdr(sock_buff);

  lets_keep_the_original_size = ntohs(iph->tot_len);

  if(iph->protocol == 1) {
    if(skb_headroom(skb) < sizeof(struct iphdr)) {
      if( 0 != pskb_expand_head(skb, (sizeof(struct iphdr))- 
                                skb_headroom(skb),0,GFP_ATOMIC) ){
        kfree_skb(skb);
        return NF_STOLEN;
    }
  }

  iph = (struct iphdr*) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr)); 
  iph->proto = IPPROTO_IP;
  iph->ihl = 5;
  iph->version = 4;
  iph->tos = 0;
  iph->tot_len = htons(lets_keep_the_original_size + sizeof(struct iphdr));
  iph->id = 0;
  iph->frag_off = 0;
  iph->ttl = 60;

  //This must be zero to be able to calculate it with csum above.                                                                          
  iph->check = 0;
  //in is the interface where the packet arrived, provided by netfilters. 
  //In PRE_ROUTING there is no out interface yet so you'll need to add 
  //the ip manually:                                                                                                                          
  ipa = (struct in_device*) in->ip_ptr;
  iph->saddr = ipa->ifa_list->ifa_address;

  //in_aton already gives you the address in network byte order .                                                                          
  //You can just add an integer, but I've chosen to use in_aton                                                                            
  //so the code is more readable                                                                                                           
  iph->daddr = in_aton("192.168.1.1");

  //Here is the important part.                                                                                                            
  iph->check = csum((uint16_t*) iph, (iph->ihl << 1));

  //Let the kernel deal with the rest for us.                                                                                              
  return NF_ACCEPT;
 }
 return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Let me know if there's anything I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks Fred for the Firm Answer. Looking for More clarification from You. Wht Exactly I am trying to do is; getting an ICMP Packet & Trying to add an Extra 20bytes IP Header over it & Want to forward the Packet to the Corresponding Out Interface [some thing like IpinIp Tunnel]. Few Queries here !! 1] If I am adding a new IP Header over the existing socket buffer with all the Fields; what is the destination IP address Kernel's Stack will look into? Will it have the logic to look the New IP & take decision OR was it my Job to steal the Packet & forward to the right out iface ?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. I'm not sure but I think it depends where your hooks are. Take a look at this http://meghadoot.sourceforge.net/files/megh_doc/netfilterArch.png - I think if your hooks are in ``local in`` the routing still hasn't happen and you don't need to worry about nothing. On the other hand, in ``post-routing`` routing has already happened. In this case you may try something like ``ip_route_me_hard(skb)`` - sorry don't remember the function name and even if I did I'm not sure if it is legal inside netfilters.

Comment: Yes.Thats a Nice Answer. Have Forgotten the basics :). I am using the PRE_ROUTING Hook. So; seems to be Kernel has not taken the Routing decision & after I forming the new Packet; hopefully it shuld look for the Newly added Header & Take Decision.well; lemme try & update later. Thanks again.

Comment: okay. I Think ; if we change the Application Layer and return NF_ACCEPT; Kernel will take care of every thing. But in my case; after adding New IP Header by taking the ICMP Packet at PRE_ROUTING Hook is Not handled by Kernel. I think; Need to STEAL it and route my self. Does that make sense ??

Comment: Actually you shouldn't need to do things like that. Can you send me the code you've already got? I can try to help you with that.

Comment: unsigned int main_hook(........,struct sk_buff *skb,....) {
sock_buff = skb;
iph = ip_hdr(sock_buff);
if(iph->protocol == 1)  {
if(skb_headroom(skb) < sizeof(struct iphdr)) {
   if( 0 != pskb_expand_head(skb, (sizeof(struct iphdr))- skb_headroom(skb),0,GFP_ATOMIC) ){
      kfree_skb(skb);
      return NF_STOLEN;
  } } 

iph = (struct iphdr*) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct iphdr));
// Filling the Header here 
/* Now Here; Looking Forward to write the code for Forwarding this skb with added IP Header */
return NF_STOLEN;
}
return NF_ACCEPT;
}

Comment: Was the code in readable format ?? if not; please let me know !

Comment: Editted my post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Given Code was able to add the IP Header over the ICMP successfully. That happened in my case too. But after that; returning NF_ACCEPT is not doing much there.I don't see any packet for the Echo (ICMP) Request that I have sent. Definitely it seems to be we need to depend on Other available Kernel API's to proceed on this further. Am in the process of investigating them & came across ip_forward_output_key(). Presently working on it.will update if any +ve result. Thanks Fred !

Comment: Update: It worked with these 4 Steps. << Var2 =_ip_route_output_key(&init_net,&rt,&fi); dst_release (sock_buff->dst); sock_buff->dst = &rt->u.dst; Var1 = dst_output(sock_buff); >>

Comment: Hi Kesav, i am doing something similar to this. How are you dealing with fragmentation for incoming packets? And, also didn't you just accept the packet instead of using dst_output function. @Fred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234344/using-netfilter-to-encapsulate-and-decapsulate-ipv4-packets?noredirect=1#comment35548201_23234344 I have question on a similar scenario.