# Using Netfilter to encapsulate and decapsulate IPv4 Packets

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, netfilter

I have two hooks in the netfilter framework.

One at `NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING` for incoming packets and other at `NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT` for outgoing packets.

**Outgoing packets:**

Now, all IPv4 Packets sent out from particular IP address, is encapsulated in another IPv4-UDP Packet.

I use `pskb_expand_head` API to have more headroom for encapsulation. And, then with `ip_route_output_key` to find the appropriate `rtable`. Using `rtable`, I reassign `skb->dst` and `skb->dev`. And, then I just go ahead and accept the packet using `NF_ACCEPT`.

```
skb_dst_drop(skb);
skb_dst_set(skb, &rt->dst);
skb->dev = skb_dst(skb)->dev;
```

**Incoming packets:**

Now, all Encapsulated Packets are received and are identified based on port number.
And, the encapsulation `(IP+UDP+XYZ HEADER)` is pulled out. And similar to outgoing packet
I use `ip_route_output_key` to get the rt(rtable).
Using rtable reassign `skb->dst` and `skb->dev`. And then i accept the packet with `NF_ACCEPT`

So, it happens that i also receive the defrags incoming packets, i am in bit of confusion how are they supposed to be dealt with.

I would want defrag packets to be queued and later receive the entire packet.
Any ideas on that. I have been going through the functions available

```
ip_defrag(skb, IP_DEFRAG_LOCAL_DELIVER);
```

But this seems like to be used for assembling packets in `NF_IP_LOCAL_IN` stage, but the i want the assembled packet in `NF_IP_PRE_ROUING` stage.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a paragraph that I've marked as *Duplicated Text* - you should delete that if it was unintentionally included.  Please help me help you make this a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4`, which is defined in `/net/ipv4/netfilter/Kconfig`,  its hooks `ipv4_defrag_ops[]` would sit at `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` and `NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT`. And your hooks should be of a priority larger than `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG`, therefore, your hooks are executed after `ipv4_defrag_ops[]`, which would do assembly for you, at `NF_IP_PRE_ROUING` stage.  After that, the `skb` goes to your hooks, should be a assembled packet.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i actually ended up using ip_derag to gather the packets in the PRE_ROUTING STAGE. `ret = ip_defrag(skb, IP_DEFRAG_CONNTRACK_IN); if (ret)  return NF_STOLEN;`